# Geoserver WMS service with CQL fitler polygon retuns always 0 matched features

Tags: cql, geoserver

I am trying to make a request with CQL filter intersects with a polygon that you can draw to my geoserver, but WFS service always returns 0 matched, I am using this configuration, and I am leaving an example polygon as filter.

```
{
            'service': 'wfs',
            'version': '2.0.0',
            'typename': 'workspace:layer',
            'request': 'GetFeature',
            'startIndex' :0,
            'count': 10,
            'CQL_FILTER' : 'intersects(geom,POLYGON((-103.33516105156251 21.13532635981934,-103.28227802846054 21.132733146568928,-103.229979857529 21.12498218902883,-103.17884473812032 21.112159207316008,-103.129437648214 21.09440598406221,-103.08230394289987 21.071918752547948,-103.03796319974948 21.044945968778553,-102.99690338665144 21.013785495572105,-102.95957542220131 20.97878123388898,-102.92638819220429 20.94031924318721,-102.89770407845843 20.898823398443987,-102.87383504794745 20.854750636568248,-102.85503934209035 20.808585849193573,-102.84151879698065 20.76083648225345,-102.8334168167928 20.712026905295165,-102.83081701391326 20.662692615193333,-102.83374252101711 20.613374339803585,-102.84215597238499 20.564612107190598,-102.8559601443285 20.516939345418038,-102.87499923773628 20.47087707655628,-102.89906077950268 20.42692826660399,-102.92787811397666 20.385572390490132,-102.9611334505628 20.347260268283343,-102.99846142920335 20.31240922524045,-103.03945316163956 20.281398624429745,-103.08366070305235 20.25456581641679,-103.13060190588125 20.232202545947004,-103.17976560527028 20.214551850743995,-103.23061708365469 20.201805482504277,-103.28260376044557 20.19410187494658,-103.33516105156251 20.191524678402207,-103.38771834267946 20.19410187494658,-103.43970501947032 20.201805482504277,-103.49055649785474 20.214551850743995,-103.53972019724378 20.232202545947004,-103.58666140007269 20.25456581641679,-103.63086894148547 20.281398624429745,-103.67186067392169 20.31240922524045,-103.70918865256225 20.347260268283343,-103.74244398914837 20.385572390490132,-103.77126132362237 20.42692826660399,-103.79532286538875 20.47087707655628,-103.81436195879652 20.516939345418038,-103.82816613074004 20.564612107190598,-103.8365795821079 20.613374339803585,-103.83950508921177 20.662692615193333,-103.83690528633221 20.712026905295165,-103.82880330614438 20.76083648225345,-103.81528276103468 20.808585849193573,-103.79648705517758 20.854750636568244,-103.77261802466661 20.898823398443987,-103.74393391092073 20.94031924318721,-103.71074668092372 20.97878123388898,-103.67341871647359 21.013785495572105,-103.63235890337553 21.044945968778553,-103.58801816022518 21.071918752547948,-103.54088445491104 21.09440598406221,-103.49147736500471 21.112159207316008,-103.44034224559604 21.12498218902883,-103.38804407466449 21.132733146568928,-103.33516105156251 21.13532635981934)))',
                'PROPERTYNAME': 'id,name'}
```

If I use the same polygon on WMS service 1.1.1, works perfectly.

This is the response:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:mapa_jalisco="mapajalisco" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberMatched="0" numberReturned="0" timeStamp="2017-03-29T22:35:42.807Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://localhost:8181/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd mapajalisco http://localhost:8181/geoserver/mapa_jalisco/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=2.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=mapa_jalisco%3Amarginacion_municipios http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://localhost:8181/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>"
```

Help me please.

Comment: As a note, different versions of WFS assume different x,y coordinate orderings.  This page may provide some more information: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/basics.html.

Comment: You are right this kind of ordering works just with 1.0.0 version, thank you.